# How to provide selective access for lambda execution to a federated user in AWS IAM policy?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, federated-identity, pingfederate

I am trying to give lambda execution access to select members within a group. Users are authenticated via PingFederate. I am having issue granting this selective access to federated user.

I have a custom IAM policy (allow-lambda-invocation-selective) attached to this role. Although the policy seems to pass validation and policy simulation shows access is allowed, when I try to execute the lambda function I get message

```
Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: User:arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/myuser1234 is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:my-lambda-function
```

Here is my policy: allow-lambda-invocation-selective

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:ListAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:123456789012:function:my-lambda-function",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:userid": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/myuser1234"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:ListLayers",
                "lambda:ListLayerVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:userid": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/myuser1234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to understand your problem. Correct me if I made a wrong supposition.

1. **Every group/user already have its own role.**

When you authenticate your users, they have their assumed role. `myuser1234`, when authenticated, will receive `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/myuser1234` role, right? Is it possible to create one role for each group and remove the `conditions` property (check item 2 explaining why)?

```
// role-for-grp-l2
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:ListAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:123456789012:function:my-lambda-function"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:ListLayers",
                "lambda:ListLayerVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

2. **The problem with `aws:userid`**

Reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) about the key `aws:userid` we can find this key has the value given by *role id:caller-specified-role-name*,

> where role id is the [unique id of the role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-unique-ids) and the caller-specified-role-name is specified by the [RoleSessionName parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html#API_AssumeRole_RequestParameters) passed to the AssumeRole request.

So `aws:userid` has value like `AIDAJQABLZS4A3QDU576Q:SomeNameYouGive`. Because this, your condition never match `arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/myuser1234` and then user cannot assume that actions.

3. **Using conditions another way**

Assuming `RoleSessionName` is the user name, you can use conditions this way:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:InvokeAsync",
                "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:ListAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*:123456789012:function:my-lambda-function",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "*:myuser1234"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:ListLayers",
                "lambda:ListLayerVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "*:myuser1234"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

if you prefer, you may remove `*` wildcard getting `role id` using AWS CLI with the command:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name ROLE_NAME
```

and changing condition as follows:

```
"Condition": {
   "StringEquals": {
       "aws:userid": "ROLE_ID:myuser1234"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Pedro.

Apologies if above was not clear. The role that every member of group gets is "role-for-grp-l2".
i.e. 

arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/

So user1s arn will be arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/user1 
While for user myuser1234 will be arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/role-for-grp-l2/myuser1234

I just want specific user within this group (myuser1234) to be allowed to execute lambda functions.
I can not create separate group and move this user (myuser1234). So i have to use a conditional.

Comment: @dadarw25 check my update out. You may compare the last part of `aws:userid` with user name.